# Один текстовый файл сам меняет свою кодировку

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, кодировка, текст

Написал программу, которая записывает в разные файлы жанр, статус просмотра и названия, с последними двумя всё хорошо, но почему-то именно жанр никак не хочет сохраняться в кодировке UTF-8. Вручную могу поменять кодировку, но при следующей записи она смениться обратно на ANSI сама по себе и вместо желаемого текста получится билеберда.
Пробовал создавать новый файл, но проблема почему-то повторилась.

Часть кода, отвечающая за запись.

```
void set_name(char *p_name) {
    ofstream outside_name("C:\\Users\\dimak\\Desktop\\C++\\Фильмы 2.0\\Name.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    outside_name.write((char*) p_name, sizeof p_name);
    outside_name.write("\n", 1);
}

void set_ganre(char* p_ganre) {
    ofstream outside_ganre("C:\\Users\\dimak\\Desktop\\C++\\Фильмы 2.0\\Ganre.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    outside_ganre.write((char*)&p_ganre, sizeof p_ganre);
    outside_ganre.write("\n", 1);
}

void set_w_unw(char p_w_unw) {
    ofstream outside_w_unw("C:\\Users\\dimak\\Desktop\\C++\\Фильмы 2.0\\W_Unw.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    outside_w_unw.write((char*) &p_w_unw, sizeof p_w_unw);
    outside_w_unw.write("\n", 1);
}
```

Пробовал вписать

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

но ситуацию это не изменило.

Comment: Это нормально, что перед ```p_name``` нет амперсанда?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов у меня изначально не хотелось ничего выводится и я "экспериментировал" и с тех пор там этого знака не стоит. Потом я раскидал потоки по функциям и всё заработало, но я забыл выставить их закрытие, так что, скорее всего, ненадолго... 
А проблему, значит, не решить?

Comment: а жанр то изначально в какой кодировке?

Comment: @Sheridan я его, как и остальное, ввожу в консоли. И в этом и суть, что меняется кодировка только у жанра.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В функцию `set_name()` вы передаете указатель на строку, и потом его же в `.write()` - всё правильно. А в функцию `set_ganre()` вы передаете указатель на строку, а внутри в `.write()` передаете уже адрес этого указателя, а не адрес строки `(char*)&p_ganre`. Вот и записывается мусор, лежащий начиная с адреса указателя. В файл записывается мусор, а не данные не в той кодировке.

```
void set_name(char *p_name) {
    outside_name.write((char*) p_name, sizeof p_name); // вместо sizeof надо strlen()
}

void set_ganre(char* p_ganre) {
    outside_ganre.write((char*) &p_ganre, sizeof p_ganre); // неправильно
// должно быть
    outside_ganre.write( p_ganre, strlen(p_ganre) );

}
```

Ну и правильно написал @AlexGlebe - количество байт для записи надо получать через `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

Команда `sizeof p_name` это константное значение, возвращающая размер типа переменной. В вашем случае размер указателя `char *`.

Писать в файл данные надо по размеру строки. То-есть используя `strlen`.

```
outside_name.write( p_name, strlen ( p_name ) );
```

При записи жанра вы передайте указатель на указатель, а потом грубо меняете тип на указатель на строку. *Меняйте жёстко тип, только хорошо подумав.*

```
outside_ganre.write( p_ganre, strlen ( p_ganre ));
```

*Команда записи в файл передаёт только байты. Ей всё равно в какой они кодировке.*